# Maven package module behaviour

Tags: java, maven

I am curious about how maven builds modules that depend on each other.

I have the following in my parent pom:

```
<modules>
    <module>app-model</module>
    <module>app-service</module>
</modules>
```

Where `app-service` depends on `app-model`.

I can run `mvn package` from the parent project, and everything works fine.

However, if I run `mvn package -pl app-service`, then maven doesn't find the `app-model` pom locally. Instead, I need to first run `mvn install -pl app-model`.

This seems like an inconsistency to me, as the first command `mvn package` works even if `app-model` is not installed.

Is there anything I can do to the parent pom so I don't have to `mvn install` the dependencies?

Comment: Just add app-model to the dependencies of app-service.

Comment: sure does @kutschkem! I just need to run `mvn package --projects app-service --also-make` or alternatively `mvn package -pl app-service -am`